# z-index not working with css3 background gradient

Tags: css

I have a background gradient on a div (only code for FF shown below for readability)

```
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(238,238,238) 0%, rgb(255,255,255) 100%);
```

I then have an image inside this that needs to "break out" the bottom over a second div below that has the same gradient. I am using z-index 2 on the image, z-index 1 on the div.

This works fine when the divs have no gradient (just a solid background colour), but as soon as I apply the gradient the z-index fails and the image drops behind the second div, see images below:

*With gradient background*
[image: with gradient]

*With solid background*
[image: without gradient]

Comment: Have you tried a higher z-index on the image (9999)? ... or possibly an overflow: visible on the containing div?

Comment: It's breaking out the container fine, but the gradient on the div below is overlapping it somehow.

Comment: @mudfalcon no, if a Z-index of 2 doesn't work, applying a much higher Z-index won't work either! That's not how Z-index is implemented.

Comment: @Mr Lister - I understand that, but in troubleshooting that would ensure it was truly at a greater z-index than the following `div`.

Comment: But it _is!_ 2 is greater than 1!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was the z-index on the containing div, even though it was set lower than the image, removing it fixed the problem :/

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to guess that the elements with the `z-index`es don't have a `position` property. Then `z-index` won't work. It may *seem* to work with no gradient, but that is because the background-color of the div is transparent an the image is visible underneath it, giving the impression of being on top.

Am I right?

Comment: They have either position relative or absolute, that's what is so strange.